# Converse of Parametric equation of plane

Tags: vectors, 3d, plane-geometry

Suppose a plane passes through a point A ( whose position vector is **a** ) and parallel to two vectors **b** and **c** . Then , to any general point on plane with position vector **r** , I can find the equation of plane as :

**r** = **a** + m**b**+ n**c**

for some scalars m and n , because to any general point **r** , the distance between **a** and **r** is a linear combination of **b** and **c** . Everything is fine and clear .

However, I am unable to prove it's converse i.e. if any plane written like

**r** = **a** + m**b** + n**c**

must pass through point with position vector **a** and must be parallel to vectors **b** and **c** . Please tell or atleast hint that how to prove it . Thanks in advance.

Comment: A given vector lies on a given plane iff the former is orthogonal to the latter's normal.

Answer (score 2):

The locus of points $\mathbf{p}$,
$$\mathbf{p} = \mathbf{a} + m \mathbf{b} + n \mathbf{c}, \quad m, n \in \mathbb{R} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
assuming $$\mathbf{b} \not\parallel \mathbf{c}, \quad \left\lVert \mathbf{b} \right\rVert \gt 0, \quad \text{and} \quad \left\lVert \mathbf{c} \right\rVert \gt 0$$
i.e. the two vectors $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ are nonzero and not parallel, by definition corresponds to plane
$$\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{r} - d = 0 \tag{2}\label{2}$$
where
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
\mathbf{r} &= \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} \\
d &= \mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{a} \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
$\times$ denoting vector cross product and $\cdot$ vector dot product.

This is because equation $\eqref{1}$ is the parametric definition of a plane, and equation $\eqref{2}$ is the implicit definition of a plane, so by choosing the correct constants for the implicit definition, the two describe the exact same plane.

How to prove this?  I am not a mathematician, but perhaps a direct algebraic proof suffices.

Substituting $\mathbf{r}$ and $d$ from equation $\eqref{2}$ to equation $\eqref{1}$ yields
$$\begin{aligned}
\left(\mathbf{a} + m \mathbf{b} + n \mathbf{c} \right) \cdot \mathbf{r} -  \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{r} &= 0 \\
\iff \quad \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{r} + m \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{r} + n \mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{r} &= 0 \\
\iff \quad m \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{r} + n \mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{r} &= 0 \\
\end{aligned} \tag{*}\label{*}$$

Due to the properties of vector cross product, $\mathbf{r} \perp \mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{r} \perp \mathbf{c}$; i.e. $\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{b} = 0$ and $\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{c} = 0$.  Therefore, for all real values of $m$ and $n$, equation $\eqref{*}$ is true, and the locus of points $\mathbf{p}$ describes the aforementioned plane.

Hopefully some mathematician member here can tell us whether this suffices as a proof, and how to express the idea more concisely (*"more elegant proof"*, as they say).

Comment: Thanks , it helped